# How does one prove that the automorphism for a cycle with more than two vertices is equivalent to dihedral group?

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory

I'm trying to prove that the automorphism group of a cycle $C_n$ with $n \ge 2$ is $D_n$, the dihedral group. It's easy to prove all of the members of $D_n$ are automorphisms of $C_n$. But I'm stuck at trying to prove that no other automorphisms exist. I'm a relative newbie to group theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to do that, you prove that any given automorphism $f$ is a member of the dihedral group. Firstly, label an arbitrary node $x$ in the cycle. $f$ must map $x$ to some node $y$ in the cycle, and must map neighbours to neighbours, so either it must go one way around the cycle or the other way, since each node has only two neighbours. The direction would correspond to the flip in the dihedral group while the offset of $y$ from $x$ would correspond to the rotation in the dihedral group. Of course, to make this intuition into a rigorous proof, you will have to number the nodes in order in the cycle and then prove these facts using induction.